# .val() fails unless its in a setTimeout - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm experimenting with different storage mechanisms for a simple JS todo app I wrote. This time I'm using localstorage. My main app.js file is pull some data from my local-storage.js file. Heres the problem, I can console.log the returned data fine but I cannot add the values to the dom with either .val() or .html() unless its wrapped in a setTimeout()? Why? Surely if the data is availble for console.log it is for .val()?

Heres the code:

local-storage.js

```
this.findById = function(id, callback) {
    var todos = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("todos")),
        todo = null,
        len = todos.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < len; i++) {

        if (todos[i].id === id) {
            todo = todos[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    callDelay(callback, todo);
}
```

and the app.js

```
findById: function(id) {

    this.store.findById(id, function(result) {

        console.log(result.title); // This works
        console.log(result.description); // This works

        // Without setTimeout() this FAILS WHY?!?!?
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#title').val(result.title);
            $('#title').attr('data-id', id);
            $('#description').val(result.description);
            $('#id').val(id);
        });

    });
},
```

As requested, the callDelay function:

```
var callDelay = function(callback, data) {
    if (callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(data);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: are you doing this in IE? IE has quirks where you have to let the browser finish painting before it will acknowledge certain modifications to the state.

Comment: Your working code isn't necessary to attach. The broken code is the more interesting part.

Comment: @Mgetz No, just chrome.

Comment: What gives without timeout: `$('#title').length`  ?

Comment: Are you calling this code before the elements are loaded on the page?

Comment: Did you add the scripts at the bottom, right before `</body>`, or wait for DOM ready? The only explanation if the value is available would be that the elements aren't.

Comment: @A.Wolff 0, so its not in the DOM - I dont fully understand why though? These scripts are loaded just before </body>

Comment: @adeneo These scripts are loaded just before </body>

Comment: So how do you add #title element to the DOM?

Comment: @A.Wolff its hardcoded on that page - <input type="text" id="title" value="" data-id="" class="target" name="title"/>

Comment: That's really strange then if you have put script just before body's closing TAG. Same result using document ready handler or window onload event? BTW, what is doing callDelay() function???

Comment: @A.Wolff I've updated my question with it - I was trying to delay the results being returned so that it acts closer to websql.

Answer (score 0):

I would wait that the dom is loaded, wrapping it to the jquery shortcut $(fn):

```
$(function(){
  $('#title').val(result.title);
  $('#title').attr('data-id', id);
  $('#description').val(result.description);
  $('#id').val(id);
});
```

Comment: I agree that's the way I prefer it, but the OP has mentioned they're loading the scripts just before `</body>` so that *shouldn't* be the issue...

Comment: This doesnt work for me. I dont want to really do this, as it works fine when I use websql to return the data ratehr than localstorage. I'm trying to keep my app the same regardless of storage method. Isnt there a way to further delay the data being passed form local-storage.js?

Comment: The point is not the result variable, that can be already there ready, but the fact that the jquery selections are not successful. What if, without the timeout, you do a console.log($("#title").length) for example?

Comment: @matteofigus I get 0, so the DOM obviously isnt ready. I'll try delay the callback in local-storage.js a little more.